# How can i calculate the remaining amount of all customer in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to calculate the `get_remaining_amount` for all customers. I am trying to retrieve the `get_remaining_amount` of all my customers. I don't understand how can i get that amount?

The `get_remaining_amount` is a remaining amount of each customer. Now i want to calculate the all customers remaining amount and show it in template

I am trying to Calculate the `get_remaining_amount` in `Customer_Collection` but i am getting this error `Cannot resolve keyword get_remaning_amount into field.`

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """Customer Model"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prop_select = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_remaning_amount(self):
        # Remaining Amount
        property_price = self.prop_select.price
        payment_done_by_customer = Payment.objects.filter(customer=self).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum'] or Decimal('0')
        return property_price - payment_done_by_customer


class Payment(models.Model):
    """Payment Model"""

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, related_name='payment')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=2, default=0.0,
                                 validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
    person = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def Customer_Collection(request):
    total_panding = Customer.objects.aggregate(Sum("get_remaning_amount"))['get_remaning_amount__sum']

    context = {
        "total_panding": total_panding,
    }
    return context
```

Comment: Please also add details of what is not working with the posted code? And, let's add the `Payment` model too.

Comment: As AKS said, plus add the `Property` model as well.

Comment: @AKS Dear please take look my question has been updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_remaning_amount` is a method. you should use field to aggregate. now i suggest you do add float or decimal field in `Customer model` and overide `save method` check this code ->

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    """Customer Model"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prop_select = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    remaning_amount = models.FloatField(null=True)

 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        property_price = self.prop_select.price
        payment_done_by_customer = Payment.objects.filter(customer=self).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum'] or Decimal('0')
        self.remaning_amount  = property_price - payment_done_by_customer
        super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
def Customer_Collection(request):
    total_panding = Customer.objects.aggregate(Sum("remaning_amount"))['get_remaning_amount__sum']

    context = {
        "total_panding": total_panding,
    }
    return context
```